# Google calendar in Django

Tags: python, django, templates, events, google-calendar-api

I'm a nobbie in Django (actually i'm a nobbie in code) and i've a question for anyone who can help me.

I want to create a event in Html input (type="datetime") and send it to my google calendar.

With the quickstart of Google Calendar I made it, but only with Static data, hardcoded in the code.

I've already search and found a lot of guides but any of them shows how to send dynamic data from my template to the calendar.

```
from datetime import timedelta

import pytz
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

service_account_email = "INSERT_HERE"
SCOPES = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar"]
credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(
    filename="FILENAME.json", scopes=SCOPES
)


def build_service():
    service = build("calendar", "v3", credentials=credentials)
    return service


def create_event():
    service = build_service()

    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
    event = (
        service.events()
        .insert(
            calendarId="CALENDARID@group.calendar.google.com",
            body={
                "summary": "Foo",
                "description": "Bar",
                "start": {"dateTime": start_datetime.isoformat()},
                "end": {
                    "dateTime": (start_datetime + timedelta(minutes=15)).isoformat()
                },
            },
        )
        .execute()
    )

    print(event)

create_event()
```

With this code when i run it in the console the event was created, but now i don't know how render this in the input (datetime, text, etc).

Any help will be nice. :)

P.S: Hope my English isn't to hard to understand

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you give an example of what you want the end result to be?

Comment: @iansedano I only need to make appointments in my Web App with the follow information: description, location, start date, end date and send it to my google calendar from my app. My problem is that i don't know how to make this form for google calendar with the information I've already have.

Comment: So your question is about how to render a form in a website with Django?

Comment: @iansedano I know how to render a form in Django, but i don't know how to connect the google calendar function to a form. Create a form from the function. Normally, we have a model, form, view (with a return render(request, '.html', context)) but i dont know how to do the same with only the function. I want to peek my date from input in html template and send the data to google calendar. I thought in create a model with start_date, end_date, description, location, user, then create a form with this fields, but my problem is that i don't know how to connect my form to google calendar in views.